# How do I activate the horizontal scroll on chart in WindowsForms Chart C#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

A lot of values are loaded at the graphics and the graphics look pretty bad.

[image: The chart]

I tried to activate the horizontal scroll so that the values were stretched on the graph, but I could not get the expected result.

The code:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == temp)
        {
            chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.Clear();
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                var transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();

                chart1.Series["Temp"].BorderWidth = 5;
                chart1.Series["Temp"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.Clear();
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Дата: ден/месец/година";
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Температура: °C";
                
                string selectTemp = "SELECT Dat,Temp FROM meteodata WHERE Station= " + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " AND Dat BETWEEN '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("_", "-") + "' AND '" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("_", "-") + "24:00" + "' ORDER by Dat";

                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectTemp, Connection);
                
                using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    transaction.Commit();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        chart1.Series["Temp"].Enabled = true;
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            //bool iii = dr.Read();
                            {
                                chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.AddXY(dr["Dat"].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(dr["Temp"].ToString()));
                                
                                listBox3.Items.Add(dr["Dat"].ToString() + " - " + dr["Temp"].ToString());
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        dr.Close();
                        Connection.Close();
                        comboBox3.Refresh();
                        comboBox4.Refresh();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        dr.Close();
                        Connection.Close();
                    }

                }

               // Connection.Close();
            }

            catch (SQLiteException err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Caught exception: " + err.Message);
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

I understand that the graph can be a scaling manually, but the goal is to automatically stretch with a horizontal scroll.

**Can I get a way how can the graphics be more understandable for the user?**

Comment: Have you tried chart1.EnableAxisXScrolling = true; ?

Comment: I receive this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Chart' does not contain a definition for 'EnableAxisXScrolling' and no accessible extension method 'EnableAxisXScrolling' accepting a first argument of type 'Chart' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WindowsFormsApp1 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MeteoAnalyzer - D.Atanasov\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\frm_main.cs 301 Active